# O365 Video Portal - anonymous public access to video

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, video

Can I allow public (anonymous/no auth) access to a video uploaded to the video portal in O365/SharePoint Online? There are some settings to "allow external users" access to certain site collections - even when I turn this one and allow external access to /search/pub I still can't access the videos without a login prompt.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, O365 Video is not targeted at a YouTube type scenario and thus anonymous or "external" access is not allowed.

EDIT: Vote on Uservoice if you want this: https://office365video.uservoice.com/forums/273864-o365-video-feedback/suggestions/7644834-allow-external-sharing

Comment: reference please?  I need proof of this, hopefully from some actual Microsoft documentation.

Comment: https://office365video.uservoice.com/forums/273864-o365-video-feedback/suggestions/7644834-allow-external-sharing - I'd suggest adding points to this UV to let Microsoft know you're interested.

Comment: @TrevorSeward, Please update your answer and include the reference link which you have provided into the comment. It will make your answer more clear. :-)

Answer (score -1):

In Office 365, you can use [Sway](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-video-and-audio-files-into-Sway-d2f14842-e103-49c0-9da2-0fbcfcad381f) to upload and display public videos.